# parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons - alternative?

Tags: php, security, parsing

Is any alternative for parse_ini_file()? Is it really so dangerous? Is a good reason to have it disabled or can I somehow convince admin that its safe?

```
parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons
```

There I've found what this error mean

[error description](http://textpattern.com/faq/232/warning-function-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)

I use in this code  (there was problem with some misspeling, but its solved and worked fine on one hosting but on another doesn't, casuse disabling that function) 
[my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274209/sort-for-czech-characters-php-issue-in-compare-function)

Comment: http://tr2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#57075 - or just search that page for "replacement".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I honestly can't find a sensible reason to disable that function but, if [parse_ini_string()](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) is available and you're also allowed to *read* files, you should have the same functionality (just in a more convoluted way). If that's not an option either, you can:

- Rewrite the binary function in plain PHP
- Find a new hosting service

Whatever is cheaper for you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Just as Álvaro González wrote, there is one very easy (not sure if promising 100%, but in some of my cases it is) solution to this. If particular shared hosting provider disables parse_ini_file function for God only knows which reason, there are `file_get_contents()` and `parse_ini_string()` functions.

So, instead of this:

```
$config_array = parse_ini_file ('/absolute/path/to/inifile.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

You do something like this:

```
$config_array = parse_ini_string (file_get_contents('/absolute/path/to/inifile.ini'), true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

Parse_ini_string accepts the same arguments after the first (string) argument, thus the result will be the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a safer function instead:

```
function parse_ini_file_quotes_safe($f){
    $r=$null;
    $sec=$null;
    $f=@file($f);
    for($i=0;$i<@count($f);$i++){
        $newsec=0;
        $w=@trim($f[$i]);
        if($w){
         if((!$r) or ($sec)){
            if((@substr($w,0,1)=="[") and (@substr($w,-1,1))=="]") {$sec=@substr($w,1,@strlen($w)-2);$newsec=1;}
         }
         if(!$newsec){
            $w=@explode("=",$w);$k=@trim($w[0]);unset($w[0]); $v=@trim(@implode("=",$w));
            if((@substr($v,0,1)=="\"") and (@substr($v,-1,1)=="\"")) {$v=@substr($v,1,@strlen($v)-2);}
            if($sec) {$r[$sec][$k]=$v;} else {$r[$k]=$v;}
         }
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```